# Block access to an ip and port using iptables on my routers

Tags: iptables, dd-wrt

I have setup 2 routers as follows:

Router (A) connects to internet, Router (B) WAN port connects to the LAN port of the Router A making it a gateway behind another gateway.

**Router A** LAN/Gateway IP: `192.168.1.1`

**Router B** WAN IP: `192.168.1.2` and Gateway IP after NAT: `192.168.2.1`

I am trying to block access to the Router A's admin page hosted on `192.168.1.1` from the LAN of Router B whose LAN IP addr are `192.168.2.1/24`. I used the following on the firewall of Router B, which seems to be failing.

`#iptables -I OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset`

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

UPDATE:
This is the solution..

`iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.1.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset`

Thanks!
KK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
Since the box works as a router, a routed paket only passes the FORWARD chain (neither INPUT nor OUTPUT).
It will work if you use the FORWARD chain instead of OUTPUT.

Comment: I tried INPUT as well, with same result. still able to open the 192.168.1.1 page from Router B LAN

Comment: Well I guess that your router setup has some rules in place in the `NAT` table. They grab the paket before it reaches the standard chains. Can you give us the output of `iptables -t nat -nL`?

Comment: here it is:
https://pastebin.com/UWXtSKzv

Comment: Ok, I see. So the point is that via the nat it does neither pass INPUT nor OUTPUT - but FORWARD! So try to insert the rule (at best as first rule) into the FORWARD chain. That should do the job.

Comment: that was it! `iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.1.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset` Thank you!